# How to add code in overleaf

Tags: code

I have to copy-paste some code in an overleaf document. But the code has tons of percentage symbols that overleaf takes as comments. I wanted to ask if there is any way I can just paste the code as it is without overleaf taking it too literally.

I'm very naive in latex so I'm sorry if this all sounds silly.

Comment: Take a look at the  `\begin{verbatim} … \end{verbatim}` environment.

Comment: @Ingmar Oh wow, I was manually adding backslashes :(  Thank you. can you write that as an answer for me to accept

Comment: @Ingmar Some of the code goes out of the page is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: @Ingmar It might be my crappy font my bad lol

Comment: Take a look at the Overleaf Help pages (linked to in my answer).

Comment: note that this is unrelated to overleaf it is core latex syntax and would be the same in any tex system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to “hide” your code from LaTeX, as it were, there are multiple options. Perhaps simplest is the `\begin{verbatim} … \end{verbatim}` environment.

Overleaf covers this topic on [their pages as well](https://overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing).